# How to skip self asserted technical profile in Azure B2C custom policy on app B if user has logged into app A?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a screen (SetDomainName-TechnicalProfile) that the user hits before login screens where I collect the email and check the domain to see if they are an internal or SSO client before sending them to login screens. I am able to get it to skip both the OpenIdConnect SSO login and the email, password (LocalAccountEmailSignin) tech profiles by setting the appropriate session management profiles. I have tried to set the session profile on this initial profile from Noop to the DefaultSSO and this causes an error when clicking on app B.

Initial sign in flow:

```
    <!-- Get the logon IP-->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="UserJourneyContext" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SimpleUJContext" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.selfasserted.welcome">
        <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="SetDomainName-TechnicalProfile" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AADFORVISUserLogin" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AADDHGUserLogin" />
        </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SetDomainName-TechnicalProfile" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SetDomainName-TechnicalProfile" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>domainName</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
        </Preconditions>
        <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADDHGUserLogin" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AADDHG-OpenIdConnect" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADFORVISUserLogin" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AADFORVIS-OpenIdConnect" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Here is the tech profile:

```
    <!--Get Domain from email (first page)-->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SetDomainName-TechnicalProfile">
        <DisplayName>Set Domain Name</DisplayName>
        <Description>Set Domain Name from signInName (email)</Description>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />

        <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.welcome</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true"/>
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopySignInNameToReadOnly" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetDomainName" />
        </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <!--changing this from Noop throws error about SetDomainName-TechnicalProfile not being in the 3rd step-->
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```